# How to join tables based on condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to write a query in such a way that,if received id matches with $id then request should join with profile table as

```
r.sent_id = profile_id
```

If sent_id matches with $id,then

```
 r.sent_id = profile_id
```

My model,

```
public function getRequestedDetails($id) {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('profile');
$stat =  $this->db->where('recieved_id', $id);
if($stat)
$this->db->join('requests enter code hereas r', 'r.sent_id = profile_id', 'left');
$stat =  $this->db->where('sent_id', $id);
if($stat)
$this->db->join('requests as r', 'r.recieved_id = profile_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('r.status', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
$list = $query->result();
return $list;
}
```

I tried this,it shows the following error

```
Error Number: 1066
```

Not unique table/alias: 'r'

```
SELECT * FROM `profile` LEFT JOIN `requests` as `r` ON `r`.`sent_id` = `profile_id` LEFT JOIN `requests` as `r` ON `r`.`recieved_id` = `profile_id` WHERE `recieved_id` = '5' AND `sent_id` = '5' AND `sent_id` = '5' AND `r`.`status` = 1
```

Can anyone help me.Thanks.

Comment: no use of adding this `$stat =  $this->db->where('recieved_id', $id);` and `$stat =  $this->db->where('sent_id', $id);` if id isset its all set, if empty its null

Comment: as wll there is separate id too `$this->db->where('sent_id', $id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
public function getRequestedDetails($id) {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('profile')
             ->join('requests','(requests.sent_id = ' . $id . ' AND requests.sent_id = profile.profile_id) 
                OR (requests.recieved_id = ' . $id . ' AND requests.recieved_id = profile.profile_id'), 'left')
             ->where('profile.status',1)
             ->get();

    $list = $query->result();
    return $list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   profile 
       LEFT JOIN requests AS requests 
              ON (requests.sent_id = profile.profile_id OR requests.recieved_id = profile.profile_id) 
WHERE  profile.recieved_id = '5' 
       AND profile.sent_id = '5' 
       AND profile.sent_id = '5' 
       AND requests.status = 1
```